# React, get bound parent dom element name within component

Tags: dom, reactjs, components, parent-child

Within my component, how can I access the name of the parent component it is nested inside?

So if my render is thus:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <RadialsDisplay data={imagedata}/>,
      document.getElementById('radials-1')
);
```

How can I retrieve the `id` name `#radials-1` from within the component itself?

Comment: You can't just use document.getElementById('radials-1')?

Comment: I have multiple renders for this component for different ids

Comment: pass 'radials-1' as a prop?

Comment: No. Needs to be more dynamic than that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It probably makes the most sense to pass it as a property, but if you *really* need to get it programmatically, and from *inside* the component, you can wait for the component to mount, find its DOM node, and then look at its parent.

Here's an example:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { containerId: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      containerId: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute("id")
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>My container's ID is: {this.state.containerId}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("react-app-container"));
```

Working demo: https://jsbin.com/yayepa/1/edit?html,js,output

---

If you do this a lot, or want to be *really* fancy, you could utilize a higher-order component:

```
class ContainerIdDetector extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { containerId: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      containerId: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute("id")
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.containerId) {
      return <span />;
    } else {
      return React.cloneElement(
        React.Children.only(this.props.children),
        { [this.props.property]: this.state.containerId }
      );
    }
  }
}

ContainerIdDetector.propTypes = {
  property: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

// Takes an optional property name `property` and returns a function. This
// returned function takes a component class and returns a new one
// that, when rendered, automatically receives the ID of its parent
// DOM node on the property identified by `property`.
function withContainerId(property = "containerId") {
  return (Component) => (props) =>
    <ContainerIdDetector property={property}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </ContainerIdDetector>
}
```

Here, `withContainerId` is a function that takes an argument called `property` and returns a new function. This function can take a component type as its only argument, and returns a higher-order component. When rendered, the new component will render the *passed* component, with all its original props, plus an additional prop specifying the parent container's ID on the property specified by the `property` argument.

You can use them with ES7 decorators (as currently implemented) if you wish, or via a regular function call:

```
@withContainerId()
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>My containers ID is: {this.props.containerId}</div>;
  }
}

// or, if you don't use decorators:
//
// Application = withContainerId()(Application);

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("react-app-container"));
```

Working demo: https://jsbin.com/zozumi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Is the state the best place for the parent ID since this isn't expected to change as component state gets updated through setState?

Comment: @DavidGlass What is the alternative? If you set it on the instance itself (e.g. `this.containerId = ...`), then you have to add a `forceUpdate` call. `setState` automatically re-renders, and the container ID *is* part of the component's state, even if it doesn't change in the future.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see where you were rendering the parent's ID to the node

Comment: I'm not certain why, but your jsbin examples no longer seem to work.

Comment: Outdated references to ReactDOM have caused the jsbin to cease functioning. Great answer though!